# How to list all aptitude user tags or the user tags for a package?

Tags: apt, aptitude

Following my [own counsel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126364/41104) I started using `user-tags` when working on projects, but now I don't remember how I called some of these tags and this cancels their usefulness. Is there a way to get those names back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following command you don't need pipes or grep:

```
aptitude search '?user-tag()' -F '%p %T'
```

This finds all packages that have a user-tag, and sets the output format with `-F` to `%p %T` for the packge name and the user-tag.

You can add anything to the search query to further limit the results, e.g. to list only installed packages with user-tags:

```
aptitude search '~i?user-tag()' -F '%p %T'
```

Comment: This also lists regular tags if they exist.

Answer (score 4):

If you installed the packages with `aptitude` and appended the `--add-user-tag <tag>` option you can list the user tags for a package by running:

```
aptitude show <package_name>
```

and the last line of the output should display the user tags.

You can use the following to search in all installed packages

```
aptitude show '~i' | grep "User Tags"
```

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: BTW, the sudo is not necessary ;)

Comment: Yes I have tested without sudo also but I have added here thinking that on some systems it will not work properly

Comment: BTW, your last command wont work if I have packages installed using dpkg, this `aptitude show '~i' | grep "User tags"` would work always.

Comment: Sorry is "User Tags" at the end.

Comment: Yes it's uppercase Tags. You can use grep -i to search for case insensitive strings

Answer (score 2):

The following commandline will return one *user tag* per line:

```
aptitude show '~T' | sed -n '/^User Tags: /{s/^User Tags: //;s/, /\n/g;p}' | sort -u
```

This will pipe the information of all packages in the package database (`~T`) to sed, which will:

- `-n` not print the *pattern space* (the line) automatically after each command cycle; together with `/User Tags/` and `p` it basically mimics grep
- `/^User Tags: /` only do the command group (`{}`) on lines matching this *regular expression*
- `s/^User Tags: //` substitute "User Tags: " at the beginning of the line with an empty string
- `s/, /\n/` substitude commata+space separating multiple *user tags* with a newline character
- `p` print the resuilting *pattern space*

sed's output (the *user tags* for each package, one per line) is then piped to `sort -u` to weed out multiple mentions of the same tag.